# What's the ratio between a hexagon's flat-to-flat width, vs corner-to-corner?

Tags: geometry, ratio

What's the ratio between a hexagon's flat-to-flat width, vs corner-to-corner?

[image]

Comment: In order for us to help you, can you please provide us with a direction of what you've tried so far and how that went?

Comment: It may be helpful to join the centre of the regular hexagon to the $6$ vertices, dividing the hexagon into $6$ equilateral triangles. Express each of the distances you want the ratio of in terms of the side length of the hexagon.

Comment: It's $\sec\frac\pi6$, by definition.

Comment: $ w/W = \cos 30^{0}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ \sqrt{3} \,\, : \,\, 2$, if the hexagon is regular.

Comment: The answer is correct. But my +1 comes when you explain how you get it.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN: The explanation comes if/when I'm convinced the OP isn't just trying to get us to do his homework for him. So far the answer ought to be useful for the OP if he needs the ratio for some practical purpose.